# ERROR: The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int

Tags: java, eclipse, loops

I've looked up similar questions with their answers and I just can't seem to figure my own version of this error out.

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks.

```
for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    if (arrivalTime[i] <= t != 0 && completion[i] != 1) {
        temp2 = (burst[i] + (t - arrivalTime[i])) / burst[i];
        if (hrr < temp2) {
            hrr = temp2;
            loc = i;
        }
    }

    t += burst[loc];
    completion[loc] = 1;
}
```

The error stems from `if (arrivalTime[i] <= t != 0 && completion[i] != 1)`

"The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int"

**(PS: It may look weird because it was translated from C++)**

Comment: What do you expect `arrivalTime[i] <= t != 0` to do?

Comment: This part is the issue: `arrivalTime[i] <= t != 0`. You can't cascade checks like that. `arrivalTime[i] <= t` will become a boolean, either true or false, that you then try to compare to 0, a numerical value. Also, I'm pretty sure that you could have used the statement from C++ as is, since Java and C++ are close enough for it to work in this case.

Comment: @AntonH The C++ version is "if (arrivalTime[i] <= t && completion[i] != 1)" and doesn't recognize the ' t ' variable because it asks me to initialize it when its already been defined

Comment: @FrancisHeroux That should work in Java also. Where is `t` declared and initialised/assigned?

Comment: @AntonH Here     `public final void highestResponseRatioNext()
{
 int[] arrivalTime = new int[6];
 int[] completion = new int[6];

 int i;
 int j;
 int t;
 int temp1;
 int temp2;
 int totalTat;
 int loc;
 int hrr;

 avgWaitTime = 0.0F;
 totalWaitTime = 0.0F; `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't "double compare" like that. try this for type int:

```
(t != 0) && (arrivalTime[i] <= t)
```

..but you probably rather want `t > 0`

Comment: Okay yeah I put in ''if (t > 0) && (arrivalTime[i] <= t) && completion[i] != 1)'' but it says the ending ')' of 't > 0' is a syntax error and should be deleted and when its deleted it doesn't recognize the variable 't' anymore and suggests it to be initialized...

Comment: Well you must of course use the parenthesis correctly. That you must be able to do

Comment: You must forgive me, I have not worked in Java for quite some time. I have already tried several variations of parenthesizing it and I'll either get the aforementioned error or I will get "Syntax error, insert ") Statement" to complete BlockStatements"

Comment: @FrancisHeroux I believe Eclipse can tell you where the missing parentheses are supposed to be..

Comment: `if (((t > 0) && ((arrivalTime[i] <= t)))` and underlines the very last close parentheses as an error

Comment: it should be `if ((t > 0) && (arrivalTime[i] <= t))`

Comment: I have tried that variation but it uninitialized my variables somehow. I'll just redo it all. Thanks